# Как с помощью JSON Schema проверить, что в объекте есть хотя одно поле?

Tags: json, валидация

Как с помощью JSON Schema проверить, что в объекте есть хотя одно поле?
Чтобы отсеивались пустые объекты без полей 
`{'field' : 48}` -- ok
`{}` -- failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указать `minProperties`

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "minProperties": 1
}
```